# drawing library need all drawing mode control by outside of map

Tags: dictionary, drawing

i am implementing google drawing library but need all drawing mode control by outside of map. but functionality will be same of drawing library

I do not know how to implement this. i have try and search google but no ref found to do this.

below is the attached image where drawing mode is outside of google map when i click circle then circle need to draw vice verca

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do write code and implemented successfully  by writing small line of code
CSS:   .gmnoprint:nth-child(5n+5){display:none;}
JS
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mapevent").click(function(){
     var clic_val = $(this).attr('attr-val');
        $( "div[role='button']:eq("+clic_val+")" ).trigger( "click" );
    });
});
</script>
HTML 
<div class="mapevent" attr-val="0">Stop Drawing</div> | <div class="mapevent" attr-val="1">Marker</div> | <div class="mapevent" attr-val="2">Circle</div> | <div class="mapevent" attr-val="3">Polygon</div> | <div class="mapevent" attr-val="4">Polyline</div> | <div class="mapevent" attr-val="5">Rectangle</div>